# Launch product unintstall from installer

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer

We have a main windows installer package, that installs a product and multiple sub-packages, which install the optional product features. These packages may be launched by user at any time after the product was installed so they're not a part of the main package.
Both main package and sub-packages are designed using WiX.

Question: would it be possible to uninstall these packages automatically when the main product is uninstalled (e.g. launch a silent uninstall during main package deinstallation or something similar)? As we know the Windows Installer cannot run multiple installation packages at the same time. Or can it, depending from the moment of the installation? For example, after InstallFinalize action or somewhere else?

Thanks,
Denis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by scheduling the uninstall custom actions after InstallFinalize action. Also, make sure they run with the msidbCustomActionTypeAsync and msidbCustomActionTypeContinue flags: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368071(VS.85).aspx